# Multiple dynamic forms submit and run function after

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I'm having troubles to get my function work properly. There are actually two problems I have.
1) Sometimes the script only adds 1 of eg 7 forms.
2) When updating the page my other function is called for every form submitted instead of just once.

So I have code that creates the form(s) if for example a user clicks a button.

```
var pp_total_change = function(){
 .. .... .
  $('.pp_count').each(function(){
  .........
     pp_total_list_items += "<li><form action='cart/add/"+$(this).attr("labelid")+"' method='post' id='form_"+$(this).attr("labelid")+"'><span>"+$(this).attr("labelname")+"</span><span class='amt'>"+$(this).val()+"</span><span>&euro; "+pp_total_price.toString().slice(0,-2)+","+pp_total_price.toString().slice(-2)+"</span></form></li>";

// which results in ->
<form id="form_51847052" method="post" action="cart/add/51847052">...text...</form>
<form id="form_51847053" method="post" action="cart/add/51847053">...text...</form>
<form id="form_51847054" method="post" action="cart/add/51847054">...text...</form>
etc...
```

Then a function which submit the forms

```
$('.temp-cart .addToCart').bind('click',function(){
        $('.temp-cart form').each(function(){
          var qty = $(this).find('.amt').text();
          var qty2 = parseInt(qty);
          var url = $(this).attr('action')+'/?quantity='+qty2+'/';

          $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "post",
            data: $(this).serialize(),
            success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
            complete: function() {
              updateStuff();
            }
          });
        });
```

Then a function `updateStuff()` that need to get fired once when all forms are done submitting.

```
 function updateStuff(){
        updateCartAjax();
        $('.order .pp_count, .pp_countsum .pp_count').val(0);
        $('.order .submit').popover('destroy').button('reset').animate({'opacity':'1'},200);
        $("html,body").stop(true, true).animate({scrollTop: 0}, 333);
        $(".pp_count").val('0');
        $("#pp_order_total ul li").remove();
        $("#pp_order_total ul").text('U heeft hiernaast nog geen producten geselecteerd.');
      }
```

So the problem I'm facing is that when a users "creates" for example 7 forms then only one of those 7 forms are submitted. When I click the submit button a second time then all forms are submitted. I thought thi shas something to do with the id's but that wasn't the case.

Second how do I run the `updateStuff` function only once after all forms are submitted?

Any help greatly appreciated...

Answer (score 1):

```
function deploy(){
    return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
        var count= $('.temp-cart form').length;
        $('.temp-cart form').each(function(){
            var qty = $(this).find('.amt').text();
            var qty2 = parseInt(qty);
            var url = $(this).attr('action')+'/?quantity='+qty2+'/';

            $.ajax({
                url: url,
                type: "post",
                data: $(this).serialize(),
                success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {},
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {},
                complete: function() {
                    count--;
                    if(count==0)
                        resolve();
                }
            });
        });
    });
}
$('.temp-cart .addToCart').bind('click',function(){
    deploy().then(function(){
        updateStuff();
    })
}
```

Comment: That seems to work (you missed a bracket at the end)! Thx... Do you also have some input for "problem 1"?? That still doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That's a runtime problem,need debug.Determine the count of '$('.temp-cart form')',when u click.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more please? If you like I have a test site [here](http://webdingetest.webshopapp.com/pvc-afzuigslang-en-of-vijverslang.html) with the full functioning script. I can't see how counting the forms would help in submitting them 1 by 1...

Comment: Your post service 'cart/add/',return httpstatus 302,302 lead to a  url redirection.This is the only thing abnornal.